# How to add multiple amount(s) of values to a struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, scope, nan

I need to create a function that can add at least 10 different x,y values to my struct

```
typedef struct Point
{
    float x, y;

}Point;

Point  createPoint(double x, double y){

    Point p[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
        if (isnan(p[i].x) == 0){
            p[i].x = x;
            p[i].y = y;
        }
    }

  for (int z = 0; z < 2; ++z){
        printf("%f\n", p[0].y);
  }

}

int main(){  
    createPoint(5, 6);
    createPoint(7, 9);
    return 0;
}
```

When printing, I get 2 values at the same number p[0], but I need to be able to reach different value at different number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array `p` is local to the function `createPoint` and goes out of scope when the function exits.  This means changes you make in one function call are not visible in the next.

Also, because you don't initialize the values of `p`, you can't depend on them containing `NaN`.  In fact, attempting to read an uninitialized variable invokes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Your `p` array should either be global or local to the `main` function so that its lifetime extends to multiple calls to `createPoint`.  You should also keep a separate counter of how many elements are currently stored in `p` so that you can write to the next available slot.

```
void createPoint(Point *p, double x, double y, int *count)
{
    p[*count].x = x;
    p[*count].y = y;
    (*count)++;
}

void printPoints(Point *p, int count)
{
  for (int z = 0; z < count; ++z){
        printf("%f\n", p[z].y);
  } 
}

int main(){  
    Point p[10];
    int count = 0;

    createPoint(p, 5, 6, &count);
    createPoint(p, 7, 9, &count);
    printPoints(p, count);
    return 0;
}
```